# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web.config

Estou tentando submeter uma action com um parâmetro assim:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action(@"Create/?reference=01/04/2016", "Cobranca")"
```

Porém ele gera uma URL assim:

```
Cobranca/Create/%3freference%3d01/04/2016
```

E causa o erro:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client
```

Coloquei no web.config os seguintes códigos:

```
 <pages validateRequest="false" />
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>
    </security>
```

Parou esse erro mas agora da erro 404 sendo que a URL deveria ser:

```
Cobranca/Create/?reference%3d01/04/2016
```

ou melhor

```
Cobranca/Create/?reference=01/04/2016
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que o sua action `Create` espera receber de parâmetro? Uma string chamada `reference` ou um DateTime chamado `reference`?

Além disso, é uma boa prática utilizar o terceiro parâmetro do `Url.Action()` para passar os valores da rota, desta forma o ASP.NET se encarregará de montar a Url e seus parâmetros para você:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Cobranca", new { reference = "01/04/2016"})"/>
```

Se reference for uma data. apenas substitua a string fixa "01/04/2016" pela sua data.

Comment: na verdade a minha action recebe 3 parametros, como enviar nesse caso?

Comment: Da mesma maneira que você fez com o reference, adicionando os parâmetros extras no objeto dinamico

    `<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Cobranca", new { reference = "01/04/2016", parametro2 =  2, andHisNameIs = "JOHNCEEENA"}) "/>`.

Lembrando que você não é obrigado a passar todos os parâmetros da sua `Action`, a não ser que sejam muito importantes para sua lógica. Os parâmetros que não forem passados apenas receberão o valor `null`.